# SignalR authentication error when using endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization()

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server side app that uses authentication.  I tried Azure SignalR as suggested by Visual Studio but after that when I am not authenticated I get a blank page instead of the typical not authorized webpage.

If I check the browser debug console, the following message appears:

"Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error: Unauthorized"

It looks this message is thrown by signalR.

If I change the line endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization(); to endpoints.MapBlazorHub() in the startup.cs file, it runs as expected.

Any idea on how to fix this?

I tried rolling back the changes made by VS, but it still doesn't work as before.

Thank you

Edit 1: This is the app.cs code for your review:

```cs
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <h1>Restricted Access</h1>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Page not found</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Edit 2:

This is the startup class

```cs
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<IdentityBDContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityBD"),
            providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure()));

             services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true; 
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true; //prevents registered users from logging in until their email is confirmed.
            }).AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityBDContext>()
              .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
              .AddUserManager<ERPUserManager>()
              .AddSignInManager<ERPSignInManager>();

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(SD.Admin, policy => policy.RequireRole(SD.Admin));
                options.AddPolicy(SD.POS, policy => policy.RequireRole(SD.POS, SD.Admin));
                options.AddPolicy(SD.AllowedTenant, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AllowedTenantRequirement(21)));
                options.AddPolicy(SD.SysAdmin, policy => policy.RequireRole(SD.SysAdmin));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
                {
                    options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
                });
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            //services.AddSignalR().AddAzureSignalR();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<CustomUser>>();



            services.AddTransient<ConfigService>();
            services.AddTransient<IdentityService>();
            services.AddTransient<TenantService>();
            services.AddHostedService<TimerUpdate>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, AllowedTenantHandler>();

            //Delete in production
            services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddCircuitOptions(options => { options.DetailedErrors = true; });


            services.AddScoped<ITenantProvider, WebTenantProvider>();
            services.AddDbContext<ERPContext>(options => options
                    //.UseLoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole()))
                    .UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("ERPDB")));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {


            using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IdentityBDContext>();
                context.Database.Migrate();
            }
            // Workaround for https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13470

            

            app.Use((context, next) =>


            {


                context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = null;


                return next.Invoke();


            });

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("mvc", "{controller}/{action}");
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is Auth being enforced on the hub? [Authorize] attribute? Your posts reads like it works only if Authenticated?

Comment: Exactly, it only works when Authenticated.  I'm using the default settings in startup.cs.  I'm updaing my question to include the App.cs file.

Comment: So you dont want Auth? Just remove it. You want a mix for methods?

Comment: So your Hub is returning an error your not capturing? Could you show the Hub Auth Implementation and your signalrR client hubconnection creation code.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I have included the startup class where all the auth implementation is.  I want authentication for the website but the application must show when the user has not authenticated.  Right now the user just gets a blank page instead of the unauthorized message.

Comment: You can't provide `RequireAuthorization` on server-side `MapBlazorHub` as that's what establishes a websocket connection to the entire application itself. If you had SignalR hubs independent of that server-side hub, you could specify authorization (and a schema if you had multiple schemes)

Comment: Thank you Ben, so how do I make sure that the server side application is protected? I indeed comment out that line and it works and the App.razor file shows that it is not authenitcated.  So it is safe to take out RequireAuthorization and still have a protected App?